# Weak Challenge Generation - Fiat-Shamir Heuristic

Tags: zero-knowledge-proofs, random-oracle-model, fiat-shamir

The Fiat-Shamir heuristic may be applied to transform a Sigma-Protocol on `R(x,w)` into a ZKPoK.

Let's call the prover's first message `a` and the verifier challenge `e`.

It is said that given a secure hash function `H`, one could have `e = H(x,a)` for Random-Oracle security.

But what happens if only `a` is hashed? What known attacks are made possible, or how is a proof of security made impossible?

Comment: I think the question you're asking was studied in [this paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f34a/588fefb18320bd307990f5a5fcd134e4d2c0.pdf)

Comment: Thanks, it seems so. I'll read it and make an answer from it.